# Matching CSS Class Selector Without Matching .io, .w3, etc

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, regex

My script matches CSS selectors in a string like this:

```
let selectors = index.toString().match(/\.-?[_a-zA-Z]+[\w-]*(?=[^{}]*\{)/g);
```

And that will match css selectors like `u-background-color-navajo-white` in declarations like this:

```
.u-background-color-navajo-white {
    background-color: NavajoWhite !important;
    background-color: var(--color-navajo-white) !important;
  }
```

However the expression also matches top domains that are included within comments in the CSS file, like `.com, .io, .org,` etc.

Anyone know how to tweak the regex such that these are excluded?

### Repository Testing

```
git clone https://github.com/superflycss/utilities-layout
npm i
sfc build
node duplicates.1.js
```

Will log:

```
    ole@mki:~/SuperflyCSS/utilities-layout$ node duplicates.1.js 
    [ '.com',
    '.com',
    '.io',
    '.io',
    '.io',
    '.md',
    '.org',
    '.org',
    '.org',
    '.w3',
    '.w3',
    '.w3' ]
```

### CLI Support

It's fixed now.  I'll be building the script into the [@superflycss/cli](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@superflycss/cli) in the near future in case anyone needs a postcss builder / duplicates checker.

Comment: I tested this out [here](https://regexr.com/43i8a), it seems to work as expected.

Comment: Hm - Strange I see that it's working in the sandbox, but when I run the same expression on the respository via the file https://github.com/superflycss/utilities-layout/blob/master/duplicates.1.js it still catches the `.io, .com` etc.  I added a link to the repository script in the question and showed how to run the script.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have changed your regex to:

```
/(?:^|[, ])\.-?[_a-zA-Z]+[\w-]*(?=[^{}]*\{)/gm
```

All it does is to add a test at the start:

Either '`start of line'` OR one of the characters: `comma` or `space` in front of the match.

This should only include CSS classes.

Comment: THAT DOES IT!!  AWESOME - THANKS!